# Select option from context menu after right click on ListView item

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to Automate one application to export data.
To export, you need to SELECT individual item from the list, Right Click and select Export (from multiple options).
So far I am able to select and right click on the Item to show the Context menu, but not able to select options under that.
How can I get reference for that Context menu and select an item under that.

I am using Python 3.7 and Latest pywinauto library

```
 syslistview = app.List1

 imageListCount = syslistview.item_count()

 for x in range(0, imageListCount):

      listview_item = syslistview.get_item(x)

      listview_item.click_input(button='right')
```

[image: I can get it to open the context menu, But can not select and click on Export]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the answer below if the control is contextmenu.

> [How to select a sub menu from a context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55628598/how-to-select-a-sub-menu-from-a-context-menu)

Comment: Thank you @Raju. Initially I tried this solution, but I was missing **from pywinauto import Desktop**.

Comment: Using the suggested link I was able to Select the menu item. How do you select Submenu? If I have submenu for **Export > "Export As BMP & Export as Jpeg"", how can I click **Export As BMP**

Comment: yes, pass the submenu title directly, it will work. <br/> 

`app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='app.exe') control=app.top_window().child_window(title='submenuTitle') control.click_input()`